# GWT treemap add mouseover/mouseout events

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, treemap

I have written a google visualization treemap wrapper for GWT.
I can successfully draw a treemap using it.
But i am stuck with mouse events.
 How can i add mouseover/mouseout event to it?

```
public class TreeMap extends Visualization<TreeMap.Options>
{
 public static class Options extends AbstractDrawOptions {
   public static Options create() {
       return JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();
   }

   protected Options() {
   }




 }

 public static final String PACKAGE = "treemap";

 public TreeMap() {
   super();
 }

 public TreeMap(AbstractDataTable data, Options options) {
   super(data, options);
 }

 @Override
 protected native JavaScriptObject createJso(Element parent) /*-{
   return new $wnd.google.visualization.TreeMap(parent);

 }-*/;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just had to add-

```
public final void addOnMouseOverHandler(OnMouseOverHandler handler) {
   Handler.addHandler(this, "onmouseover", handler);
}
```

full example [here](http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.in/2012/03/gwt-wrapper-for-visualization-treemap.html)